# Who is Community?

Tags: support

I see in mi yodeya question, "modified by community"

 In the post itself it is not possible to see the modification.

What is it? Who are the authors?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's the [Community user](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/u/-1). This is how he describes himself:

> Hi, I'm not really a person.
>
> I'm a background process that helps keep this site clean!
>
> I do things like
>
> - Randomly poke old unanswered questions every hour so they get some attention
> - Own community questions and answers so nobody gets unnecessary reputation from them
> - Own downvotes on spam/evil posts that get permanently deleted
> - Own suggested edits from anonymous users
> - Remove abandoned questions

Basically, it's the "user" the computer puts in when there is no user to be there. What you're probably noticing is the first function (bumping old unanswered questions so they get attention).

See more on the [Meta.SE FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19739/166155).